# Get a flat view of a list of torch tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

Given a list of tensors `lst`, how can I get a flattened view of all their elements? I can get a copy with `flat = torch.hstack([t.flatten() for t in lst])`, but I would like any changes done on the `flat` to be visible in their original list elements.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to modify the original tensors; would something like this work?

```py
for i, t in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = t.flatten()
```

You could then run `torch.hstack` again on `lst` to get the combined tensor.